# Show pages and posts with 'true' checkbox value and sort 'em

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, filter

not much add to the subj... I know how to do the first part:

```
$args = array('post_type' => array('post', 'page'), 
                'category__not_in' => array(7), 
                'meta_key' => 'show_on_main', 
                'meta_value' => true);
```

And the second part of the task should be something like this:

```
$args = array ('post_type'  =>  array('post', 'page'),
                 'category__not_in' => array(7),
                 'meta_key' => 'sorting_on_main',
                 'orderby'   => meta_value_num,
                 'order' => ASC);
```

But how can I do it both at the same time? I tried to do it with array in 'meta_key' value, but it didn't work out

Comment: What are you sorting by? What is 'sorting_on_main'? Also, if you could add line breaks to your arrays they would be much more readable.

Comment: I have to show on a main page checked pages and posts in specific order... 'sorting_on_main' is a meta field, by value of which I do the sorting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'        => array('post', 'page'), 
    'category__not_in' => array(7),
    'meta_query'       => array(
        array(
            'key'      => 'show_on_main',
            'value'    => '1',
            'compare'  => '=='
        )
    ),
    'meta_key'         => 'sorting_on_main', 
    'orderby'          => meta_value_num,
    'order'            => 'ASC'
);
```

Comment: @johnnyd23 I have checkbox(added via metabox) for pinning my news items and trying to show post which had been checked last at the very top but seems it is not working right some shows at the top some at the bottom or middle. here is my code $args_meta = array( 'post_type' => 'news-section', 'meta_query'       => array(array( 'key'      => 'pinned_news_item', 'value'    => '1', 'compare'  => '==' ) ), 'meta_key'         => 'pinned_news_item',  'orderby'          => meta_value_num, 'order'            => 'DESC');